# Mocha and Chai testing setTimeout() inside a function that returns a promise

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

Hello stackoverflow so I have a function that is called timeout which does this.

```
export function timeout<T>(promise: Promise<T>, millis: number, contextName?: string): Promise<T> {
  let contextPrefix = "Request";
  if (contextName) {
    contextPrefix = contextName;
  }
  return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      logger.info(() => `${contextPrefix} timed out.`);
      reject(new Error(`${contextPrefix} timed out.`));
    }, millis);

    promise
      .then((response: T) => {
        if (timer) {
          clearTimeout(timer);
          resolve(response);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        const msg = (err as Error).message || (err as string);
        logger.warn(() => `${contextPrefix} error: ${msg}.`, {}, err as Error);
        if (timer) {
          clearTimeout(timer);
          reject(err instanceof Error ? err : new Error(msg));
        }
      });
  });
}
```

I was able to get all lines covered and 80% branch coverage. The only 2 branches that are not covered, is the promise that is being passed in. Specifically,

```
if (timer)
```

How can I write a mocha and chai unit test that will cover the `if(timer)` branch. For some reason my coverage is reporting that `if(timer)` branch is not covered however I am getting 100 percent line coverage. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Test cases:

`index.ts`:

```
export function timeout<T>(promise: Promise<T>, millis: number, contextName?: string): Promise<T> {
  let contextPrefix = 'Request';
  if (contextName) {
    contextPrefix = contextName;
  }
  return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      reject(new Error(`${contextPrefix} timed out.`));
    }, millis);

    promise
      .then((response: T) => {
        if (timer) {
          clearTimeout(timer);
          resolve(response);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        const msg = (err as Error).message || (err as string);
        if (timer) {
          clearTimeout(timer);
          reject(err instanceof Error ? err : new Error(msg));
        }
      });
  });
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { timeout } from '.';

describe('75688542', () => {
  test('should resolve', async () => {
    const mPromise = Promise.resolve('test');
    const res = await timeout(mPromise, 10);
    expect(res).toEqual('test');
  });
  test('should reject', async () => {
    const mPromise = Promise.reject(new Error('test'));
    await expect(() => timeout(mPromise, 10)).rejects.toThrow('test');
  });
  test('should timeout', async () => {
    const mPromise = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
    await expect(() => timeout(mPromise, 10)).rejects.toThrow('Request timed out.');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75688542/index.test.ts (8.762 s)
  75688542
    ✓ should resolve (3 ms)
    ✓ should reject (1 ms)
    ✓ should timeout (14 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   93.75 |       50 |     100 |   93.75 |                   
 index.ts |   93.75 |       50 |     100 |   93.75 | 4                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.599 s, estimated 10 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```